# HTTPS connection timeout after disabling SSL v3.0 and switching to SHA 256

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, ssl, https

Our server is Windows Server 2012 with IIS 8.5 and we run several web applications on it.

Last week, we disabled SSL v3.0 and implemented Forward Secrecy on our server for the POODLE attack. And we also released a new version of our web applications. The CPU went up to 30%-40%(normally it is 10-20%). Other than that, things were running smoothly.

This Monday, we renewed our certificates from SHA1 to SHA256 and we had the new certificates installed on our server. The installation went fine and apps ran perfectly fine after that.

Then things got ugly as this Tuesday **some of our clients could not access our application via HTTPS. Requests for a small JS file cannot be completed and timed out. Errors like Net::ERR_TIMED_OUT were returned in Chrome.
Meanwhile, requests via HTTP were okay and completed fast.**

**The CPU sometimes went up and down from 10% to 70%-80% and then to 10%.** And the server has plenty Memory resource.

We could not figure out why and we restarted the apps several times and it didn't work.

So after a while, **we re-enabled SSL v3.0 and disabled Forward Secrecy and rebooted the server.**

Finally everything went back to normal again, but we still don't know the root cause.

All we did were disabling SSL v3.0, implementing Forward Secrecy and upgrading to SHA 256. Could any of these cause the connection timeout?

Has anyone encountered this kind of issue? Or do you have any suggestion about how to pinpoint the root cause and resolve this issue?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Henry

Answer (score 0):

I already replied to your IIS.net forum thread that both TLS 1.0 and SHA-256 certificate have client compatibility issues (some clients/browsers just fail to support them).

In your case, do more data collection about the clients and dive into the failures can provide your more insights.

Hire a security expert to assist is by far the best for your team, as you lack of the skills.

Comment: Lex, thanks for your reply. I made a comment in the IIS forum. I will post it here.

We did do a full check about our clients and there are very few clients using old platforms. After the changes, everything was normal and no clients complained about this. Our clients can smoothly access our app with HTTPS.  And then as I mentioned, on this Tuesday, our clients and ourselves could not access our app all of a sudden. And previously the app ran fine for our clients and ourselves.  And we were using latest Chrome and Firefox and IE which has no compatibility issue with TLS and SHA 256.

Comment: So the question is why did our apps become not accessible this Tuesday? Is there a possibility that IIS or the operating system has a limit for HTTPS request but not for HTTP? Does IIS has different queue for HTTPS and HTTP requests?

The number of requests was normal in Worker Processes of IIS and the operating system was normal except for a little high CPU usage.  HTTP requests for our app completed fast but not so for HTTPS request.